# How is this code synthesizeable in FPGA? Is this synthesizeable in ASIC too?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Below

```
module model #(parameter
  DATA_WIDTH=32
) (
  input [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] din,
  output logic dout
);
logic [$clog2(DATA_WIDTH):0] accum;

int i;
assign dout = (din[0] ~^ din[DATA_WIDTH-1]);
always_comb begin
    for(i = 1; i < (DATA_WIDTH+1)/2 ; i++) begin
        assign dout = dout & (din[i] ~^ din[DATA_WIDTH-1-i]);
    end
end

endmodule
```

This is code for palindrome bit verification, it doesn't look synthesizeable with the recursive combinational dout

I'm just confused and curious, can anybody explain? Should i just use macro to do expand

```
assign dout = (din[0] ~^ din[DATA_WIDTH-1]) & (din[1] ~^ din[DATA_WIDTH-2]) & ... ;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot use assign inside an always block.

```
assign dout = dout & [some logic];
```

Secondly, this is not synthesizable as this is creating a feedback in a combinational circuit.

You can iterate the always_comb block through the input bits to check for palindrome property. The use of a for loop with an if statement ensures that the logic remains synthesizable, as below:

```
module model #(
  parameter DATA_WIDTH=32
) (
  input [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] din,
  output logic dout
);

integer i;

always_comb begin
    dout = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < (DATA_WIDTH + 1) / 2; i++) begin
        if (din[i] != din[DATA_WIDTH-1-i]) begin
            dout = 0;
        end
    end
end

endmodule
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.. I have update my response. But since this a single bit, it can be implemented with simple `and` or `Xor` logic as well.

Answer (score -1):

There is a number of syntax problems with your code. I'm assuming you ask about the following equivalence:

```
module model #(parameter
  DATA_WIDTH=32
) (
  input [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] din,
  output logic dout
);

int i;
always_comb begin
    for(i = 1; i < DATA_WIDTH/2 ; i++) begin
        dout = dout & (din[i] ~^ din[DATA_WIDTH-1-i]);
    end
end

endmodule
```

Yes, it's synthesizeable, FPGA or ASIC irrelevant.

Concept: Every synthesizeable combinational logic can be treated as a **[lookup table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table)**(LUT) -- there is a certain value of output, for any possible value of input. The logic in `always_comb` block is clearly satisfied.

Below is an intuitive implementation (code snippet):

```
wire [(DATA_WIDTH/2) -1 :0] lower_part, upper_part, upper_part_rev, part_xor;

//cut din in half
assign {upper_part, lower_part} = din;

//reverse bit order of upper part
generate
    genvar i;
    for(i = 0; i < DATA_WIDTH/2; i = i+1) begin
        assign upper_part_rev[i] = upper_part[(DATA_WIDTH/2)-1-i];
    end
endgenerate

//bitwise XOR the 2 parts
assign part_xor = lower_part ^~ upper_part_rev;

//bit AND reduction and output
assign dout = &part_xor;
```

Extra fact: one typical FPGA implementation is a huge set of programmable LUTs.